# differences between aspx and jspx? and which one?

Tags: asp.net, jspx

What are the differences between aspx and jspx? and Why should I choose aspx or jspx?

what is the best software to develop web poject with jspx?

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

**aspx**

- microsoft
- .net
- on version 4, 10ish years old

**jspx**

- open source
- java
- dev started in feb 2008

What should you choose? Depends.  Need more context.